# SpotLight is not seen - OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am doing a project on spotlight in OpenGL. I guess I wrote the code correctly but I couldn't able to see a round spot in my output. Your help would be much appreciated. Here I am writing my fragment shader file and light definition.

fragmentShader.fs

```
#version 330

in vec3 N; // interpolated normal for the pixel
in vec3 v; // interpolated position for the pixel 

// Uniform block for the light source properties
layout (std140) uniform LightSourceProp {
    // Light source position in eye space (i.e. eye is at (0, 0, 0))
    uniform vec4 lightSourcePosition;

    uniform vec4 diffuseLightIntensity;
    uniform vec4 specularLightIntensity;
    uniform vec4 ambientLightIntensity;

    // for calculating the light attenuation 
    uniform float constantAttenuation;
    uniform float linearAttenuation;
    uniform float quadraticAttenuation;

    // Spotlight direction
    uniform vec3 spotDirection;
    uniform float  cutOffExponent;
    // Spotlight cutoff angle
    uniform float spotCutoff;
};

// Uniform block for surface material properties
layout (std140) uniform materialProp {
    uniform vec4 Kambient;
    uniform vec4 Kdiffuse;
    uniform vec4 Kspecular;
    uniform float shininess;
};

out vec4 color;

// This fragment shader is an example of per-pixel lighting.
void main() {

    // Now calculate the parameters for the lighting equation:
    // color = Ka * Lag + (Ka * La) + attenuation * ((Kd * (N dot L) * Ld) + (Ks * ((N dot HV) ^ shininess) * Ls))
    // Ka, Kd, Ks: surface material properties
    // Lag: global ambient light (not used in this example)
    // La, Ld, Ls: ambient, diffuse, and specular components of the light source
    // N: normal
    // L: light vector
    // HV: half vector
    // shininess
    // attenuation: light intensity attenuation over distance and spotlight angle

    vec3 lightVector;
    float attenuation = 1.0; 
    float se;


    // point light source
    lightVector = normalize(lightSourcePosition.xyz - v);

    //Calculate Spoteffect
    // calculate attenuation    


 float angle = dot( normalize(spotDirection),
                 normalize(lightVector));
    angle = max(angle,0);   

   // Test whether vertex is located in the cone
   if(acos (angle) > radians(5))
 { 

  float distance = length(lightSourcePosition.xyz - v);
   angle = pow(angle,2.0);

 attenuation = angle / (constantAttenuation + (linearAttenuation * distance) 
        +(quadraticAttenuation * distance * distance));

           //calculate Diffuse Color  
   float NdotL = max(dot(N,lightVector), 0.0);

   vec4 diffuseColor = Kdiffuse * diffuseLightIntensity * NdotL;

   // calculate Specular color. Here we use the original Phong illumination model. 
   vec3 E = normalize(-v); // Eye vector. We are in Eye Coordinates, so EyePos is (0,0,0)  

   vec3 R = normalize(-reflect(lightVector,N)); // light reflection vector

   float RdotE = max(dot(R,E),0.0);

   vec4 specularColor = Kspecular * specularLightIntensity * pow(RdotE,shininess);

   // ambient color
   vec4 ambientColor = Kambient * ambientLightIntensity;

  color = ambientColor + attenuation * (diffuseColor + specularColor);   

  }   
   else
       color = vec4(1,1,0,1); // lit (yellow)


}
```

The light definition in main.cpp

```
struct SurfaceMaterialProp {
    float Kambient[4]; //ambient component
    float Kdiffuse[4]; //diffuse component
    float Kspecular[4]; // Surface material property: specular component
    float shininess; 
};

SurfaceMaterialProp surfaceMaterial1 = {
    {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f},  // Kambient: ambient coefficient
    {1.0f, 0.8f, 0.72f, 1.0f},  // Kdiffuse: diffuse coefficient
    {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f},  // Kspecular: specular coefficient
    5.0f // Shininess
};

struct LightSourceProp {
    float lightSourcePosition[4]; 
    float diffuseLightIntensity[4];
    float specularLightIntensity[4];
    float ambientLightIntensity[4];
    float constantAttenuation; 
    float linearAttenuation;
    float quadraticAttenuation;
    float spotlightDirection[4];
    float spotlightCutoffAngle;
    float  cutOffExponent;
};

LightSourceProp lightSource1 = {
    { 0.0,400.0,0.0, 1.0 },  // light source position
    {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},  // diffuse light intensity
    {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},  // specular light intensity
    {1.0f, 0.2f, 0.0f, 1.0f}, // ambient light intensity
    1.0f, 0.5, 0.1f,   // constant, linear, and quadratic attenuation factors
    {0.0,50.0,0.0},  // spotlight direction
    {5.0f}, // spotlight cutoff angle (in radian)
    {2.0f} // spotexponent
    };
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Do you receive an error?

Comment: no. I am unable to see spot properly

Answer (score 2):

The order of a couple of members of the `LightSourceProp` struct in the C++ code is different from the one in the uniform block.

Last two members of the uniform block:

```
    uniform float cutOffExponent;
    uniform float spotCutoff;
};
```

Last two members of C++ struct:

```
    float spotlightCutoffAngle;
    float  cutOffExponent;
};
```

These two values are swapped.

Also, the cutoff angle looks suspiciously large:

```
{5.0f}, // spotlight cutoff angle (in radian)
```

That's an angle of 286 degrees, which isn't much of a spotlight. For an actual spotlight, you'll probably want something much smaller, like `0.1f` or `0.2f`.

Another aspect that might be giving you unexpected results is that you have a lot of ambient intensity:

```
{1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f},  // Kambient: ambient coefficient
...
{1.0f, 0.2f, 0.0f, 1.0f}, // ambient light intensity
```

Depending on how you use these values in the shader code, it's likely that your colors will be saturated from the ambient intensity alone, and you won't get any visible contribution from the other terms of the light source and material. Since the ambient intensity is constant, this would result in a completely flat color for the entire geometry.

Comment: Thanks for the response I did what you said. My output is same. Plse see my output https://imageshack.us/i/hlHRDikrp

Comment: It looks like you might have way too much ambient intensity. I added some text to the answer.